# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps and empty dependency lists for "on mount"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I believe that I've picked up an anti pattern when switching from class to functional components with react and am trying to make sense out of the situation.

This is what i would normally do, but `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` is now getting in the way.

```
type ChildProps = {
  onMount: () => void
}
const Child = ({ onMount }: ChildProps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    onMount()
  }, [])
  return <div>i am a child</div>
}
const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Child onMount={() => console.log('foo')} />
      <Child onMount={() => console.log('bar')} />
    </>
  )
}
```

What i expect to happen:

1. `<Parent/>` component creates the two `()=>console.log(...)` functions **every frame**
2. `<Parent/>` component passes **a new** `onMount` prop to a `<Child/>` component (because of the point above, it's a new reference)
3. `<Child/>` component captures the first ever reference of `onMount` passed in, during it's life cycle (because of the empty deps) and invokes it

While it may not be obvious just from the semantics of "props" and "deps" what is happening, this (anti) pattern seems like its fairly common.
To reiterate, while `onMount` may change and be different every time a mounted `<Child/>` is rendered, **i dont care** and i want the effect to do exactly what i've expressed here - **fire `onMount` only once ever during the life of the component** and just ignore any subsequent changes of `onMount`.

The eslint rule disallows this, and forces me to do:

```
const Child = ({ onMount }: ChildProps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    onMount()
  }, [onMount]) //<--- add the dep
  return <div>i am a child</div>
}
```

Unfortunately, now i have to change the `<Parent/>` and cache the callback. Otherwise, `onMount` wont really be on mount it will become an "on render" since it will fire in every frame.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const logFoo = useCallback(()=>console.log('foo'),[])
  const logBar = useCallback(()=>console.log('bar'),[])
  return (
    <>
      <Child onMount={logFoo} />
      <Child onMount={logBar} />
    </>
  )
}
```

This may be the proper react way to address this anti pattern. I guess bottom up:

1. child enforces the dep rule, if something is called from an effect, it has to be passed as a dep
2. prop is cached so that it is not recreated with every render

The issue is, i still prefer the way the anti pattern allowed me to express myself. If something is called "on mount" in a component, it implies that it should be relevant only to that single event and point in time. If the component has already mounted, changing the "on mount" handler should not trigger anything nor be relevant.

In isolation `<Child/>`'s effect can now be triggered many times during it's life from the outside, which is what i wanted to prevent.

Is `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` valid in this case, ie. is having an effect such as this to expose the single "on mount" effect an anti pattern?

I'm thinking of one way of avoiding it that might still comply to all the react patterns, but it feels like an even more verbose escape hatch:

```
const Child = ({ onMount }: ChildProps) => {
  const firstRef = useRef(onMount)
  useEffect(() => {
    firstRef.current()
  }, [])
  return <div>i am a child</div>
}
```

Since nothing will update the ref during the life of the component, i get the same effect :/

Comment: What makes you think `useEffect(() => { onMount(); }, [])` is anti-pattern? It's a mounting effect.

Comment: There is no issue here, if you want to use your old method then define `onMount` inside of the `useEffect`, otherwise use `useCallback`, and pass it to the dependency array, that's the proper and suggested way of using `useEffect` with a dependency array. Your anti pattern is confusing because you have a dependency in your effect that is not accounted for in it's dependency array, introducing ambiguity.

Comment: “Define inside of the useeffect” you mean pass it as a dep? 

I don’t think it’s an anti pattern, but it seems that there is a different school of thought :)

Comment: Empty dependency array to run once after mounting is a completely valid use case. The linter isn't able to tell the difference, though, and since you typically ***do want*** effects to rerun when their dependencies update, it [linter] is just opinionated about including them.

Comment: The linter only does what the person that set it up told it to. Hence it may be subjective whether an ignore is allowed or not. I feel that the ref, filled only once would abide by the rule, but to me it feels even weirder than the empty dep. Perhaps I could get more mileage by wrapping this particular effect into a custom hook where linter is ignored and perhaps centrally documented why that is happening.

Comment: You could wrap the parent onMount creation in useCallback, and store the fn that onMount calls in a ref, and in onMount call `myOnMount.current()` to avoid updating the onMount changing the child. Similar to https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: I think i'm leaning towards that `[]` as deps is indeed considered an anti pattern, and that making a custom hook to wrap any kind of awkward but correct logic is the way to go. I see `[]` as a "built in" shorthand to that type of a hook, but if it's bad it's bad :/

Comment: Empty dependency array isn't anti-pattern, not sure where you are getting this from. See [Conditionally firing an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect): "If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array (`[]`) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works."

Comment: "Your anti pattern is confusing because you have a dependency in your effect that is not accounted for in it's dependency array, introducing ambiguity." ive gotten something along these lines IRL . I should have that link to the docs handy, that seems like argument enough :)

Comment: You seem to not have understood what I meant when I said "Define inside the useEffect" I meant define the on mount function inside of the callback for the useEffect, then there is no need to pass anything to the dependency array.

Comment: @DrewReese maybe "anti-pattern" is too strong of a word, but the React docs say this: "If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect will always have their initial values. While passing [] as the second argument is closer to the familiar componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount mental model, there are usually better solutions to avoid re-running effects too often. Also, don’t forget that React defers running useEffect until after the browser has painted, so doing extra work is less of a problem."

Comment: Here is the "better alternatives" they are referring to, several of which I've already suggested here. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Comment: @CoryHarper It depends entirely on the specific use case, which is generally a case-by-case decision on what implementation/pattern to use. No need to over engineer an effect if simply using an empty dependency array suffices. I don't disagree though, the "alternatives" really depend on what actually needs to be done.

Comment: I'm just quoting the React docs, in this case the various alternatives work perfectly fine and you couldn't really call them overengineering, either define the function in the effect or make sure it has a stable identity across renders and you have your on mount effect, it'll be the same lines of code either way and the dependency array will be serving the purpose it was actually meant to, keeping track of the dependencies in the effect. It's not of huge harm to use the empty array, I'm not trying to suggest that.

Comment: How do i define it if it's being passed from the outside?

Comment: That solution is only possible if you can bring the logic of the function itself into the child component, otherwise you have to go with `useCallback`.

Comment: Why is this not documented somewhere as a common opinion based issue?